# Show that the full Fourier series of $F$ converge pointwise to $F$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

> Let $f$ be a piecewise continuous function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, with $\int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx=0$. Define 
>   $$
> F(x)=\int_{-\pi}^{x}f(y)dy.$$ 
>   Show that the full Fourier series of $F$ converge pointwise to $F$.

**Definition**. An infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ pointwise in $(a,b)$ if it converges to $f(x)$ for each $a< x < b$. For each $a < x< b$ we have 
$$
\lim_{N\to \infty}\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)\right| \rightarrow 0
$$ 
Since we have $\int_{- \pi}^{x} f(x) dx=0$, for all functions $f_n$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, they converge to $0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you want $F(x) = \int_{-\pi}^x f(y)\; dy$, not $\int_{-\pi}^\pi$.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify on what you mean by your second-to-last sentence: it is a bit too vague to interpret.

Also, note that $F$ is of bounded variation, this might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function $f$ is integrable, it is bounded. It follows that the function $F$ is Lipshitz, so its Fourier series converges pointwise, see, for instance,  [Fich, 684]. See more on pointwise convergence of Fourier series in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence).

*References*

[Fich] Grigoriy Fichtenholz, *Differential and Integral Calculus*, v. III, 4-th edition, Moscow: Nauka, 1966, (in Russian).